# ElasticSearch total distinct occurrences across whole data

Tags: elasticsearch

I am very new to ElasticSearch (version 2.3.3) and this is my following format for the data.

```
{   
   "title": "Doc 1 title",
   "year": "14",
   "month": "06",
   "sentences": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
          "class": "Introduction",
          "synth": "intr"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "text": "Donec molestie pulvinar odio, ultricies dictum mi porttitor sit amet.",
          "class": "Introduction",
          "synth": "abstr"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "text": "Aliquam id tristique diam. Suspendisse convallis convallis est ut condimentum.",
          "class": "Main_Content",
          "synth": "body"
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "text": "Nunc ornare eros at pretium faucibus. Praesent congue cursus aliquet.",
          "class": "Main_Content",
          "synth": "body"
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "text": "Integer pellentesque quam ut nulla dignissim hendrerit.",
          "class": "Future_Work",
          "synth": "ftr"
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "text": "Pellentesque faucibus vehicula diam.",
          "class": "Bibliography",
          "synth": "bio"
        }
    ]
}
```

And, multiple documents such as doc1, doc2, ..., doc700.

I am trying to generate such a query that I get the total number of occurrences of every different "class" across my whole document bulk sorted by year.

So, the outcome would be something similar to the following.

```
{
   "year" : "14",
   "count" : [
       { "Introduction" : 1357 },
       { "Main_Content" : 1021 },
       { "Future_Work" : 490 },
       { "Bibliography" : 241 }
   ],
   "year" : "15",
   "count" : [
       { "Introduction" : 972 } ,
       { "Main_Content" : 712 },
       { "Future_Work" : 335 },
       { "Bibliography" : 81 }
   ]
}
```

Is it possible to achieve what I am posting? Or, would it be easier to do it for every "class"?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done using the [Nested Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html). If your existing mapping does not have nested mapping then you can perhaps use the following:

```
    {
    "mappings": {
        "book": {
            "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "month": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "year": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "sentences": {
                "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "synth": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "id": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "text": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "class": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then run the following query:

```
    {
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "years": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "year"
            },
            "aggs" : {
                "sentences" : {
                    "nested" : {
                        "path" : "sentences"
                    },
                    "aggs" : {
                        "classes" : { "terms" : { "field" : "sentences.class" } }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the sample data:

```
    "aggregations": { 
    "years": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
        {
            "key": "14",
            "doc_count": 2,
            "sentences": {
                "doc_count": 12,
                "classes": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                    {
                        "key": "introduction",
                        "doc_count": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "main_content",
                        "doc_count": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "bibliography",
                        "doc_count": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "future_work",
                        "doc_count": 2
                    }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "key": "15",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "sentences": {
                "doc_count": 5,
                "classes": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                    {
                        "key": "main_content",
                        "doc_count": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "bibliography",
                        "doc_count": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "future_work",
                        "doc_count": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "introduction",
                        "doc_count": 1
                    }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
        ]
    } 
}
```

Do not get confused with the doc_count here, they're the true occurrences of your "class" inside the main doc. They are actually stored as nested documents tied to the main document.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried mapping like you have suggested, but when running the query I get {
            "type": "aggregation_execution_exception",
            "reason": "[nested] nested path [sentences] is not nested"
         }

Comment: Could you verify if the mapping is correctly created for the index?

Comment: Yes, when I run -XGET /index/_mapping/type it gets the mapping, though I have to say that the data I presented in the question is not the whole data. I am trying to map the specific part that's important for the query, the rest(which I ommited) is not relevant for the query and does not contain any of the fields I want to search&count

Comment: Interesting. Btw, if you're running the query against existing data it won't work. You'll have to migrate the data so it get indexed with new mapping. There is no way to get around it :( is that the case here?

Comment: So, you are suggesting I create a new index with the mapping property, and load files into the new index?

Comment: Also, should there be any field specifying what "book" is?

Comment: In my context "book" was just the document type, so no need of another field. Try with a new index and see how it goes.

Comment: buraluit, you are an absolute monster! When you told me that the book was the type, that thing clicked the whole thing actually. That was the piece that did not match in my whole scenario. Of course, I am eternally grateful for your support and knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest Aggs within each other, and using the terms aggregation will split the results into buckets and count them like you are hoping for. An example would be

```
POST index/type/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "agg1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "year"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "agg2": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "sentences.class"
          }        
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I haven't tried this with a nested array of objects before, but it should still work. Some more helpful information can be found here

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/aggregations-and-analysis.html

Comment: Thank you for the very quick reaction. Yes, this query ALMOST works as I wish, but the return of the second aggregation only returns the doc_count, and not the occurrence count. Counting the number of occurrences of a particular class along every document belonging to a certain year is the true question.